# my Android app is run correctly in emulator but I can't find it in the emulator's apps menu

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using Android Studio V1.3 and I have a problem with exporting my app in emulator or real device!. when I run the app from Android Studio in the emulator, the app runs but app icon is not shown in emulator's apps menu, As well as when I export my program to apk and install it on my device, installation is always successful but the open button in install confirmation is not active and I can't find the app in apps menu to open it! <>

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aidin.zardast.avecalc" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".secondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

logcat

```
08-03 15:06:37.438  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ Not     late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
08-03 15:06:39.478  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,   referenced from method  android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-03 15:06:39.478  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 412: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-03 15:06:39.478  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-03 15:06:39.478  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-03 15:06:39.478  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 434: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-03 15:06:39.478  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-03 15:06:42.938  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 134K, 7% free 3014K/3216K, paused 34ms, total 35ms
08-03 15:06:43.118  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 22.905MB for 20864016-byte allocation
08-03 15:06:43.148  11582-11591/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 1% free 23386K/23592K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
08-03 15:06:45.018  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 1% free 23394K/23592K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
08-03 15:06:45.128  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 34.900MB for 12574128-byte allocation
08-03 15:06:45.188  11582-11591/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 35672K/35872K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
08-03 15:06:45.958  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
08-03 15:06:45.958  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 375: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-03 15:06:45.958  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-03 15:06:45.968  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
08-03 15:06:45.968  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 377: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-03 15:06:45.968  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-03 15:06:46.728  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 1% free 35693K/35872K, paused 78ms, total 78ms
08-03 15:06:46.918  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 53.383MB for 19360016-byte allocation
08-03 15:06:46.988  11582-11591/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 54599K/54780K, paused 62ms, total 62ms
08-03 15:06:48.548  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8117848, tid 11582
08-03 15:06:48.658  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-03 15:06:48.688  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-03 15:07:40.478  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
08-03 15:08:01.868  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-03 15:09:13.968  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-03 15:09:26.118  11582-11587/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-03 15:09:26.428  11582-11587/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-03 15:09:28.988  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-03 15:09:45.828  11582-11587/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-03 15:09:46.288  11582-11587/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-03 15:10:07.708  11582-11582/com.aidin.zardast.avecalc W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set this to your launcher activity

```
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
```

Comment: thanks a LOT!! Android Studio miss that code but eclips! it works now:))